# eCommerce product lists - read more buttons or no buttons?

Tags: gui-design, buttons, e-commerce, hyperlinks

On a product list where the only option to add to cart is through the product detail page - would a button on the card in the list hurt or improve UX / conversion. Some sites use "buy" on the list, but in reality it only opens another url (detail page). Without button the product lists are cleaner, but we users tend to be drawn to click on buttons.

So do you add a read more and label it buy, or leave the button all along?

Comment: Not sure this has an answer, I mean you can get an opinion on it, but to be scientific you would need an A/B test on your specific target audience.

Comment: Opions are good, and if anyone knows if it has been A/B tested that would be great! I see that more of the bigger "online stores" in Norway removes the buttons from productlistings.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the user likely understands they are on an ecommerce site, I would leave the button off entirely from your Product Listing Pages.

The entire content area essentially functions as the button/CTA to your Product Detail Pages.  Typically you only add other clickable areas on a product tile if you have additional functionality available besides a link into the PDP (ie favoriting, color swatches, swiping through several thumbnails, etc). Those usually only show up on a hoverstate so the consumer can more easily evaluate each product in the list via a large, clear image.

Comment: Agreed, as long as the content area is clearly clickable, that should act as the CTA. Having a 'Buy' button which doesn't perform an expected action (adding to the cart or proceeding to a payment page) could cause confusion

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly.

You have pages with dozens of little cards, one card per product. If you click on a product, it takes you to "product detail page", where you can click on the "Buy" button that takes you to the "cart page".

You seem to be doing perfectly fine there.

---

For wholesale shops, the buttons may be convinient. For a shop where your customers routinely buy dozens of "staplers, pins, notebooks, coffee beans, tissue paper, napkins, light bulbs", customers would like to click the "buy" button in the product card and expect it to be added to the cart directly (without changing the page). You will still have an option to click on the product to go to the "details page", but most of the repeat customers, would prefer to click "buy, buy, buy" and click "check-out".

Answer (score 0):

One month ago I got this similiar case, which after several researches and A/B testing, I decided to take off the "detail" button and changed it into a text with link "More Detail" after short description of the products, this also give your primary CTA stand alone to get more attention from the users.

But there is no silver bullet for this case, you must have an A/B testing / research for your product because my target audience and yours isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest something else rather using read more link or read more button. Use descriptive labels instead of standalone Read More text, your copy will benefit in several ways:

1. Links will be more accessible.
2. Links will be more enticing to users and potentially more
   persuasive.
3. Users will feel more confident as they click from page to page.
4. More keywords on the page will help search-engine optimisation.
5. Meaningful links will stand alone and help users who are scanning
   the page.

I don't know what is your product but if someone have electronics product website and they have coffee machine XYZ page, then they should use "See What Else You Can Find About coffee machine XYZ". If you find yourself relying on Read More as standalone link labels, remember that they create uncertainty for users and are bad for accessibility.

**Source:** [Nelson Norman Group "Learn More Links"](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/learn-more-links/)